# using the value of an argument to access an object property

Tags: javascript, json

This is the simple currency converter script which gets the currency rate from JS library - it's based on the last value in JSON chaining (PLN, EUR etc. ) ->

```
    var priceAmount = amount;
    var currencyRateUSDPLN = Currency.rates.PLN;
```

I know that I can't pass the function argument straight to Currency.rates.PLN, what is the shortest way to achieve this functionality ?

```
function convertCurrency (amount, to) {
    var priceAmount = amount;
    // here I want to pass 'to' argument (EUR, PLN for example)
    var currencyRateUSDPLN = Currency.rates.to;
    var pricePLN = ( priceAmount / currencyRateUSDPLN ).toFixed(2);
    console.log(pricePLN + ' PLN');
}
```

The Currency object contains -> [link](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/javascripts/currencies.js)

Comment: what is `Currency.rates.PLN`?

Comment: it returns the currency rate from JS library, the value is something about 0.27

Comment: Without knowing what the object `Currency.rates` contains, there's not much we can help with, but shouldn't `var currencyRateUSDPLN = Currency.rates.to;` just be `var currencyRateUSDPLN = to;` as you'd be passing the `Currency.rates.PLN;` to the function?

Comment: I've updated the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the question you are trying to ask is how can you use the value of an argument to access an object property.

you can do this using bracket notation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

```
function convertCurrency (amount, to) {
    var priceAmount = amount;
    // here I want to pass 'to' argument (EUR, PLN for example)

    var currencyRateUSDPLN = Currency.rates[to];
    // If 'to' argument passed in is "EUR" then this
    // will resolve to Currency.rates.EUR

    var pricePLN = ( priceAmount / currencyRateUSDPLN ).toFixed(2);
    console.log(pricePLN + ' PLN');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I meant this exactly :), I'll change the question title for your suggestion. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to interpolate the `to` value via square brackets (`[]`). So:

```
Currency.rates[to]
```

Alternatively, instead of passing strings in to the function and interpolating them, you could just pass the currency rate reference directly:

```
function convertCurrency (amount, to) {
    console.log(( amount / to ).toFixed(2) + ' PLN');
}

convertCurrency(34.56, Currency.rates.PLN)
```